# How to keep ASCII value in normal string?

Tags: python

I'm working on converting an integer value to a high/low message like this:

```
def int2message(integer):
    messageHigh=chr(integer//256)
    messageLow=chr(integer%256)
    return [str(messageHigh),str(messageLow)]
```

and here is the example:

```
>>testValue=int2message(10)
>>print(testValue)
['\x00', '\n']
```

Now, I want to append this result to the end of the list like this:

```
['0xA2', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, '00', '0n']
                                                        |     |
                                                       high  low
```

but I find that it's hard to save ASCII values as a normal string. I can't use `replace()` to delete `\x` and `\` and other operations of normal strings.

When I print `\x00` and `\n` separately, they are invisible.

Is there any good idea to deal with this problem?
And is there any better format to convert integer values to normal strings?

Comment: `'0n'` is a strange way to write `\0xa`. Why do you want there to be the leading `0` and why do you drop the `\\`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using ASCII or one of its 8bit derivatives (to be able to print all code points below 256), you must know that:

- all code points below 32 are control characters. Specifically `'\x00'` is the NULL character and `'\x0a'` (or `'\n'`) is LineFeed
- character `'\x20'` (32) is the space character
- only code points between 33 (`'!'`) and 126 (`'~'`) are normal printable ASCII characters
- character 127 is the DEL (not printable) character
- character from 128 to 255 have different representation depending on the charset. For example `'\xe9'` prints as `é` in Latin1 charset and `'Ú'` in CP850 charset

Said differently, you can store any value below 256 in characters (or bytes in Python 3), but you cannot print them directly. Convert them in hexa with `hex` or in their decimal value string with `str` if you want to print them.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer, I'm afraid as I'm not entirely clear on what you want output. The decimal number 10 gives the ASCII character \n (which is a line feed). I assume that when you convert that to a string, you want an invisible line feed (and not any *actual* character output). Making the following adjustments will give you that.

```
def int2message(integer):
    messageHigh=chr(integer//256)
    messageLow=chr(integer%256)
    return [str(messageHigh),str(messageLow)]


testValue=int2message(10)
testValue = bytearray(testValue)
print(testValue)
```

Output is simply a space followed by a line feed (so the cursor moves but no text is output).